# How do I use custom characters in a java string?

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt files in java using random characters. I have created these characters using the private character editor app in windows 10.

However, when I replace letters in a string with these custom characters, the letters are replaced with "?" instead of the desired character.

How can I make it so the letters will be replaced with the desired characters?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the character.

[image]

```java
String text;
                
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(text.replace("a", ""));
    }
                
    br.close();
```

Comment: @user please check the edit I just posted. What do I need to change?

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that be a font matter really?

Comment: Would I need to create a font with all of these custom characters and then import the font into eclipse?

Comment: It will probably help if you show some code illustrating what you tried.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "custom characters"? The `char` type is just integer values. The glyph that is displayed for a given value depends on the font used in your OS terminal or your GUI app.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The custom character I referred to is the screenshot I posted. Also, I didn't really try much via code. I just used String#replace() to replace certain letters with that character.

Comment: @ElliottV4 And you expect the terminal to use your png file when you do `System.out.println()`? If so, you need to create a custom font.

Comment: You're facing an [X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)... you're fixated on a solution to a symptom, but you have some other (real) problem that you're ignoring. You need to add code that demonstrates how you use this character to encrypt your data. Are you using some metrics from the character? Are you interpolating the actual character? Provide some details, or you're going to be stuck in this dead end for a while.

Comment: It looks like Private Character Editor is a tool that comes with Windows 10. You will need to find a way to load the characters you create with this tool from the operating system.

Comment: What displays `?` instead of the desired characters? Can you include the code you're using to display these characters in the question

Comment: @Joni Check the edit I just posted.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Check the edit to see the code.

Comment: OK. A simple [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). Can you use a random character from some other Unicode font to do what you want? But then, you probably want to show us how you plan to unravel your encryption -- what are you using for a key? What other characters are you planning to substitute?

Comment: I was just testing an idea that I had. I don't really have an exact approach in mind. As of right now, I'm testing to see if I can replace values in strings with these custom characters that I made.

Comment: There are two aspects, 1) glyphs, and 2) character encoding and decoding. The latter is supported by the CharsetProvider class. Your custom CharsetProvider will return a Charset class that defines decoding and encoding methods for your charset. I don't know how to bring your glyphs into Java but, as others noted, it's not Java that needs them it's every other program that will display the encoded bytes of your charset.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that you are trying to write this text to the console with `System.out.print`. Console output is fairly limited for a number of reasons, most of all because the console UI is not drawn by your program, so you have limited control over it. You need to create a graphical user interface if you want to display these characters.

The simplest GUI there is, is showing a message dialog:

```
String text = "";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
```

The second problem is, that the GUI has to use the *custom* *font*  you create with the private character editor app. That's how this "character editor" works: it  creates a custom font, which is then used by other Windows applications. After some digging, I've found that the editor saves the custom font as a [TTE file](https://fileinfo.com/extension/tte) which is a file format I've never heard of before. There is a standard [Java API to load custom fonts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html) but I'm not sure if it will support the files created by the "private character editor".

If you're serious about creating custom fonts, you may want to switch to using more standard font editing software such as [FontForge](https://fontforge.org).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this.